# wrap function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How do you wrap a function into another function so i can call it in code behind?

So this is the code I need to wrap and get it called to a function:

```
$(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
    });
 });​

<div id="container" style="width:340px; height:270px;"></div>
```

I was told I can put this into a wrap and then call the function. How can this be done?

This data is dummy, my data is coming from the server. What i want is to redraw the chart in code behind so it refreshes the data, using RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: What task are you solving? What are you trying to achieve? It's not very clear from  your description

Comment: this data is dummy, my data is coming from the server. what i want is to redraw the chart on code behind so it refreshes the data, using RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 string someScript = "<script language='javascript'>container_highcharts();</script>";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function container_highcharts() {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    }
</script>
```

in code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
     string someScript = "<script language='javascript'>container_highcharts();</script>";
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);
}
```

Comment: my chart isnt showing now, this data is dummy, my data is coming from the server. what i want is to redraw the chart on code behind so it refreshes the data, using RegisterClientScriptBlock

Answer (score 2):

Define the following general function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function container_highcharts(chartTitle, xAxisCategories, yAxisTitle, seriesArray)
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: chartTitle
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: xAxisCategories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: yAxisTitle
                    }
                },
                series: seriesArray
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then in code-behind, register this function call with dynamic parameters like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string chartTitle = GetChartTitle();
     string xAxisCategories = GetXAxisCategories();
     string yAxisTitle = GetYAxisTitle();
     string seriesArray = GetSeriesArrayAsString();

     string someScript = String.Format("<script language='javascript'>container_highcharts({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});</script>", chartTitle, xAxisCategories, yAxisTitle, seriesArray);
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);
}
```

This will register your script which will be run on page load.

Comment: +1, But passing a root data object would be beter instead of passing each data attr as a parameter.

Comment: for series you have series, seriesArray, what about the data!

Comment: @mali, How are you getting the data on server side? If you're getting it as an object, just pass that data object as a function paramater. For clarification, you should add an example data that you dynamically get on server side.

Comment: m ali, I have removed it to make it dynamic, the data is passed to the Javascript function as a parameter.

@ocanal Good catch, wrapping data a single object is another way of doing it. +1

Comment: @mali, you should build a string containing the data and pass it to the Javascript function.

Comment: it is no obligation, you may or you may not, depending on your personal preference.

Comment: do you have an online link for me to check?